# highcharts link series such that turn one off turns off the other

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I would like to link a pair of series in highcharts so that clicking either one in the legend turns both in the pair on/off.

For example, [in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GCqsf/), if I click `1A` in the legend I would like it to also turn off `2A` but leave `1B` and `2B` unaffected. Clicking `2A` should also turn off `1A`, i.e. the link should work both ways.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to handle the `legendItemClick` event and specifically hide (and show) the "sister" series.

I have a running example [in this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ssarabando/GCqsf/1/).

Note that I'm using the `links` variable as an easy way to get the "sister" series for a given series.

Also note that I've added an `id` to each series so that `chart.get()` returns the series when given its id.

Comment: That's great. Say I have an id that is output with the data that indicates which "family" each series belongs to. Is there a way to do it without the `sisterseries` array? E.g. like in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GCqsf/2/

Comment: The `id` should be unique or else you can't use `chart.get()`. In such a case you would have to filter `chart.series` for the "family" instead. It's kinda "dirty" to subvert `id` like that, but it works: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ssarabando/GCqsf/3/).

Comment: ah ok, your first method is probably the more elegant way. My data was from php but I managed to write a script to make a "sisters" array. Many thanks.

Answer (score 12):

You can also use `linkedTo` options from Highcharts, see: http://jsfiddle.net/GCqsf/4/

<s>There is only one limit - linked series isn't displayed in legend, so probably it may not fit the best your example.</s> Since Highcharts 3.0.7 you can set `series.showInLegend = true` to display linked series in legend.

Comment: It is a good suggestion and useful to know but you're right, I need all the series in the legend so not ideal for this problem

Comment: FYI: Since Highcharts 3.0.7 you can simply set `showInLegend` for linked series, so they will be displayed anyway.